# Why has the Hayate no Gotoku anime switched studios so many times?

Tags: anime-production, hayate-no-gotoku

The anime version of Hayate no Gotoku has been done by three different studios so far:

- Season 1: [SynergySP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SynergySP)
- Season 2: [JC Staff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.C.Staff)
- Movie, Season 3, Season 4: [Manglobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manglobe)

Each studio's version is a little different. For example, SynergySP focused a lot on parody while JC Staff focused more on romance.

I've seen a few shows switch studios once, but switching twice seems extremely rare.

Why has it switched studios so many times? Was the creator unsatisfied with what the previous studios did to the story? Was it just some financial matter?

Answer (score 10):

(I'm Japanese, so please excuse my English.)

First a bit of background:

- Season 1: This season was a Sunday morning anime in Japan. Sunday morning anime means children anime. SynergySP is known as an anime studio for children.
- Season 2: After this season, *Hayate* moved to the midnight anime for adults in Japan. To produce an anime for adults is the contrary to the SynergySP's corporate philosophy.

After that, you can read the *Hayate*'s author, [Hata's thought](http://websunday.net/backstage/hata/391.html):

> TVアニメが始まります。
>
> 第三期ではありません。
>
> 今回は新アニメ。
>
> 新しいハヤテのごとく！です。

Translation

> The TV anime will start.
>
> It is not the 3rd season.
>
> It is a new anime.
>
> *New Hayate no Gotoku!*

As for your question:

> I've seen a few shows switch studios once, but switching twice seems extremely rare.

Typically when the timeslot moves from a morning/children anime to the midnight/adults anime, often times you will see a studio switch.

Comment: So in summary, what is being said is that because the anime shifted to an older target audience the change from SynergySP to JC Staff happened, and after the movie the production went in a different creative direction (for various reason due to feedback)?

Comment: Hata also write that '劇場版で試した方法論を そのままTVシリーズにフィードバックして 今回の新アニメは作られています。(I tried new representation on the movie. New TV anime made from the movie feedback.)'

Comment: It is typical that the TV anime studio is different from the movie anime studio too. I think that Hata takes good feedback from the movie studio Manglobe :D

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand about the 'what is ~ happened'.
I have an idea of the cause of the 1st switch too.
I did say the midnight anime is adults anime, and the morning anime is children anime.
The typical morning anime focuses the comedy and the heroism, but the romance is not important.

Comment: However, originally manga Hayate is the romance comedy.
When a midnight anime airs 3 a.m., Japanese otaku calls it 深夜27時アニメ(27 o'clock midnight anime).
We did call 1st season Hayate 深夜34時アニメ(34 o'clock midnight anime).
Of course it is 10 a.m. morning anime, but when the anime has many romance or some adult representation, we put like that.
I think that the reason of the 1st switch is 深夜34時アニメ :D

Comment: for future additions, please edit your answer instead of commenting on you answer.